# Rails error identify an object passing 2 attr in url to change boolean of third attire

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, attributes, routes

I want to identify my object "zucode" and change boolean "active" to true. Probably seems strange but Im using several models that need auth, and complete solutions like devise, authlogic and others, for this use case in particular, don't make the cut. Thanks in advance for any help.

I get this error :
undefined local variable or method `zucode' for #

in this line in controller
    zucode = Zucode.find_by_zucode_id_and_zucode_saa_secret(params[:zucode_id],params[:zucode_saa_secret]).update_attributes(:isactive => true)

zucodes_controller

```
def activate
zucode = Zucode.find_by_zucode_id_and_zucode_saa_secret(params[:zucode_id],params[:zucode_saa_secret]).update_attributes(:isactive => true)
```

end

I have tried adding `, :method => :put` at the end off line in controller but i get the next error in the same line.

```
/app/controllers/zucodes_controller.rb:77: syntax error, unexpected =>, expecting keyword_end ...(:isactive => true), :method => :put ... ^
```

Link in email

```
To activate  click this link:
<a href="http://localhost:3000/zucodes/<%= @zucode.id %>/<%= @zucode.saa_secret %>/activate">Activate this</a>
```

Routes

```
get 'zucodes/:id/:saa_secret/activate' => 'zucodes#activate'
```

i also tried adding the following to route but getting error

```
:via, [:get, :put]
```

error:

```
/Users////config/routes.rb:6: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting keyword_end ...tivate' => 'zucodes#activate' :via, [:get, :put] ... ^ /Users////config/routes.rb:6: syntax error, unexpected '\n', expecting :: or '[' or '.
```

Comment: Thanks, I used 2nd option, works perfectly,.. You guys rock!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your controller:

```
Zucode.find_by_id_and_saa_secret(params[:id],params[:saa_secret]).update_attributes(:isactive => true)
```

Although this might be better:

```
zucode = Zucode.where( id: params[:id], saa_secret: params[:saa_secret] ).first
if zucode && zucode.update_attributes(isactive: true)
  # flash update successful
else 
  # flash zucode not found or update failed
end
```